# Unable to open video source from second window in electron video chat app (First window opens video source fine)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, peerjs

I am trying to create a video chat app with electron. I modified the code for a web based video chat based on peerjs and socket.io to work with electron. The web app code works fine and multiple tabs can connect to the same room with video. But when I run the electron version and try to connect to a room from a second window ,the devtools console throws the error `index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source` and the video is not loading in the second window. All the code is given below.

PS: I am running peerjs server locally on port 3001 and socket.io server on 3000

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On OS X it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static('public'))



io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('User connected')
  socket.on('join-room', (roomId, userId) => {
    socket.join(roomId)
    socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-connected', userId)

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      socket.to(roomId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnected', userId)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.2.0/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js" defer></script>
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #video-grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
      grid-auto-rows: 300px;
    }
    
    video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  Hello
  <div id="selectRoom">
    <label>Type the room number</label>
    <input id="roomNumber" type="text" />
    <button id="goRoom">Go</button>
  </div>
  <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
var inputRoomNumber = document.getElementById("roomNumber");
var btnGoRoom = document.getElementById("goRoom");
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
//const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')

btnGoRoom.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(inputRoomNumber === '') {
    alert('Enter a room number')
  }
  else{
    const ROOM_ID = inputRoomNumber.value
    console.log(ROOM_ID)
    const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: '3001'
    })
    const myVideo = document.createElement('video')
    myVideo.muted = true
    const peers = {}
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: false
    }).then(stream => {
      addVideoStream(myVideo, stream)
      myPeer.on('call', call => {
        call.answer(stream)
        const video = document.createElement('video')
        call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
          addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
        })
      })
    
      socket.on('user-connected', userId => {
        connectToNewUser(userId, stream)
      })
    })
    
    socket.on('user-disconnected', userId => {
      if (peers[userId]) peers[userId].close()
    })
    
    myPeer.on('open', id => {
      socket.emit('join-room', ROOM_ID, id)
    })
  }
})




function connectToNewUser(userId, stream) {
  const call = myPeer.call(userId, stream)
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  call.on('stream', userVideoStream => {
    addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream)
  })
  call.on('close', () => {
    video.remove()
  })

  peers[userId] = call
}

function addVideoStream(video, stream) {
  video.srcObject = stream
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
    video.play()
  })
  videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

Comment: Please see answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63548532/7678133 - may shed some light?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelAtterbury but the web version of the same app works fine and the same camera feed is loaded when tested from multiple chrome tabs as different clients. For some reason it is not working with electron.

Comment: Does the web version work with multiple browsers or multiple chrome tabs? The OS may differentiate the two and two electron apps may be like testing the web version on multiple browsers.

Comment: Thanks it does not work when I tested chrome and opera together. When I try to connect with opera after opening a window in chrome it throws the same error in console.  @MichaelAtterbury

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot Use Only One Camera For Two Applications. You have to use two Cameras for that.

It will Throw that error Because Your Operating System Doesn't Allow Your Second App to use Camera when One App is Using Camera.