# peerjs / webrtc DOMException on the webview2 control

Tags: wpf, webrtc, peerjs, webview2

i have a working (audio/video) peerjs sample that work both in localhost and online

https://github.com/jsanahuja/peerjs-webcam

the only changes i have made is this

```
  var peer = new Peer('sender', {  path: '/', debug:3 });
```

so i have removed the server and port
and like i said , it just works ! both in local and on my website

but when i put the caller code (sender.html) in a webview2 control hosted in wpf application
i get an error in the console

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source
> ```

i have tried to load the html url from local and from online , both give the same error

```
webview.Source = new Uri("https://mywebsite.com/static/sender.html");
```

and

```
webview.Source = new Uri("file://C:/Dev/Samples/0WEBRTC-Samples/peerjs-webcam- 
master/sender.html");
```

any idea on how to solve this is much appreciated, thanks .

Answer (score 0):

ok i will answer my own question :p

you cannot access the webcam from two differents processes , my bad .

credit to the real answer :

[Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Could not start video source , Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63542923/uncaught-in-promise-domexception-could-not-start-video-source-uncaught-erro)

now i have tested the website from my phone and the wpf app from my computer and it worked just fine .